# ¿Cómo mostrar un mensaje mediante un "echo" dentro del formulario login? PHP

Tags: php

La idea es esta, una vez que el usuario haya iniciado sesión 3 veces, se cumple la condición de `if($numSession<3)`. Obviamente los números de cantidad de sesiones, se guardan en una tabla `usuarios` de la base de datos *MySQL*.

Debería salir el siguiente mensaje, `demasiadas sesiones abiertas`, pero el detalle es que *PHP* me redirecciona dentro de la misma pestaña, solo para mostrarme el mensaje, y pues, la idea es que muestre ese mensaje dentro del formulario *login*.

Base de datos:

```
          Base de datos login

  ___________tabla usuarios_____________
 |                                      |
 | idusuario int(11) autoincrement,     |
 | usuario varchar(50),                 |
 | password varchar (50),               |
 | numSession int(1)                    |
 |______________________________________|

if($numSession<3){      
    $sql2 = "UPDATE usuarios set numSessiones = numSessiones + 1 where usuario_db = '$usuario'";
    $resultado2 = $conexion->query($sql2);
    header('location: inicio.php');
    }else{
        header('location: index.php');
        //mostrar este mensaje "echo" una vez que la pagina haya sido redirrecionada por el header('location: index.php').
        echo "demasiadas sesiones abiertas";
    }
//...
```

Código completo.

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once 'conexion.php';

$usuario = $_POST ['usu'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
$sha1_pass = sha1($password);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario_db ='$usuario' AND password_db = '$sha1_pass' ";
$resultado = $conexion->query($sql);

if($resultado->num_rows>0){

    while ($registro = $resultado->fetch_array()) {

        $numSession = $registro['numSessiones'];
        $nombre = $registro['usuario_db'];
        $_SESSION['nombre_usu'] = $nombre;


        if($numSession<3){
            $sql2 = "UPDATE usuarios set numSessiones = numSessiones + 1 where usuario_db = '$usuario'";
            $resultado2 = $conexion->query($sql2);
            header('location: inicio.php');
        }else{
            header('location: index.php');
            //mostrar este mensaje "echo" una vez que la pagina haya sido redirrecionada por el header('location: index.php').
            echo "demasiadas sesiones abiertas";
        }   
    }
    }else{
        echo "usuario incorrecto";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Lo que te está redireccionando es `header('location: inicio.php')` debes de ver en que otro momento haces ese redireccionamiento para que se cumpla lo que quieres, y además sería mejor que dentro del echo pusieras un alert de JS: `echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("demasiadas sesiones abiertas");</script>';` si no el puro echo solo imprimirá ese texto en alguna parte de tu página sin alertar de verdad al usuario.

Comment: Disculpe también se podría hacer al revés, primero que redireccione al index.php y luego mostrar un mensaje?

Comment: Si, puedes poner en tu string de la URL `index.php?mensaje='demasiadas sesiones abiertas'` y lo tomas desde PHP con `$_GET` y mandas la alerta, esta es solo una de muchas formas en como puedes hacerlo, esta la usaría yo y es la que te recomendaría.

Comment: Hola lo que tu deseas hacer es que cuando ejecutes en **header('location: inicio.php')** en la pagina se muestre el mensaje que tienes abajo.

Comment: Hola Yoel, acabo de editar el código, la idea es la siguiente, lo que quiero es que muestre este echo cuando la pagina ya ha sido redirrecionada al index.php.

Comment: @kyle Viendo que estás recibiendo respuestas con métodos completamente diferentes entre uno y otro, te recomendaría editar la pregunta para poder aclarar con todo el detalle posible qué es lo que se intenta hacer. Una descripción más precisa del resultado esperado probablemente haga que obtengas mejores respuestas

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta, espero haberme expresado bien. agradecería mucho sus respuestas.
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer peticiones al servidor sin recargar debes usar AJAX con Javascript. AJAX es en resumen el hacer peticiones asíncronas al servidor y que puedo mostrar o cambiar porciones del HTML de acuerdo a la respuesta que recibas.

Debes leer sobre este tema y la creación del objeto HttpXMLRequest, no es complejo pero si no has usado JavaScript debes estudiarlo para poder hacerlo.

Comment: Hola, se podrá hacer sin AJAX?
acabo de editar el código para que se entienda mejor.

Comment: Acalarcion sumando a lo de @Mariano, siendo que no es una respuesta per se, mas como una aclaracion a la pregunta, deberia ir en comentarios. Sin embargo no concuerdo con los votos negativos por el esfuerzo. Te recomendaria que pases esta pregunta a un comentario y sigas aportando como hasta ahora!

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tienes que hacer es guardar los datos en una variable de sesión y en la página del ***index.php*** imprimir el contenido.Te dejo el ejemplo:

```
    <?php
 session_start();

include_once 'conexion.php';


 $usuario = $_POST ['usu'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
$sha1_pass = sha1($password);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario_db ='$usuario' AND password_db = '$sha1_pass' ";
$resultado = $conexion->query($sql);

if($resultado->num_rows>0){

    while ($registro = $resultado->fetch_array()) {

        $numSession = $registro['numSessiones'];
        $nombre = $registro['usuario_db'];
        $_SESSION['nombre_usu'] = $nombre;


        if($numSession<3){          
        $sql2 = "UPDATE usuarios set numSessiones = numSessiones + 1 where usuario_db = '$usuario'";
        $resultado2 = $conexion->query($sql2);
        header('location: inicio.php');
        }else{

            header('location: index.php');
      //mostrar este echo una vez que la pagina haya sido redirrecionada.
       $_SESSION['msg'] = "demasiadas sesiones abiertas";
        }   
    }
}else{
echo "usuario incorrecto";
}
?>
```

> En el ***index.php*** colocas el siguiente código en donde desees que se imprima el contenido.

```
    <?php 
       session_start();
       if(isset( $_SESSION['msg'])){
               echo  $_SESSION['msg'];
               unset($_SESSION['msg']);
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si te comprendo bien, quieres realizar el proceso que indicas sin que se refresque la página que esta siendo vista. Lo cual puedes lograr invocando el código PHP via Ajax, y pidiendo que te imprima el resultado en un elemento html. Te envío un ejemplo:

```
$.ajax({
            url:url_del_proceso,
            data: 'dato='+dato1,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                $('.alert').html(data);

            }
    });
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien el ejemplo, recién estoy empezando a programar en php y todavía no he visto el tema de AJAX.
De igual forma muchas gracias.

Comment: Quizá si compartes un poco más de detalles de tu proyecto sea más facil ayudarte.